# Fuzzy border in display for small windows or popups Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, unity, display

On my Asus K53S laptop, when I have a window open which is not maximised, there is a thick border around it consisting of coloured lines and dots.

Unfortunately I dont have enough rep to post a pic. That would show the problem very clearly.

Any idea what is causing this? It is really annoying because that border blocks out other things, and also the 'close', 'minimise', 'maximise' buttons are not visible (its just colourful fuzz).

My laptop has just come back from a repair where the DC power jack was replaced (which entails taking apart most of the laptop). Could this be related?